# How to check if a booking between two dates is possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

An `Offer` has a number of `places`. It means that each day `places` bookings can be made for this offer. An `Offer` `has_many` bookings.

A `Booking` has a `date_begin`, a `date_end` and `belongs_to` an `Offer`. It means that each day between `date_begin` and `date_end` one place is used regarding the associated `Offer`.

Given a requested booking for an offer, how should I check if it can be validated?

Example :

```
- offer has 2 places (offer.places == 2).
- offer has currently 3 bookings (offer.bookings.count == 3)
- First booking B1 is between 01-04-2016 and 10-04-2016
- Second booking B2 is between 01-04-2016 and 05-04-2016
- Third booking B3 is between 08-04-2016 and 10-04-2016.

offer.available_between?("01-04-2016", "10-04-2016")
=> false (because of B1 and B2, and because of B1 and B3)

offer.available_between?("01-04-2016", "05-04-2016")
=> false (because of B1 and B2)

offer.available_between?("08-04-2016", "10-04-2016")
=> false (because of B1 and B3)

offer.available_between?("06-04-2016", "07-04-2016")
=> true (because there is only B1 during this period)
```

Here is a try:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base

  # True if and only if each day between date_begin and date_end has at least one place left.
  def available_between?(date_begin, date_end)
    (date_begin.to_datetime.to_i .. date_end.to_datetime.to_i).step(1.day) do |date|
      day = Time.at(date)
      nb_places_taken_this_day = self.bookings.where("date_begin <= :date AND date_end >= :date", date: day).count
      return false if nb_places_taken_this_day >= self.places
    end
    true
  end

end

offer.available_between?(booking.date_begin, booking.date_end)
```

I don't feel confortable with this at all especially because there are multiple separated SQL queries.

Can you see a better way to achieve this using ActiveRecord more efficiently?

Comment: I've read your description multiple times and still don't understand when available_between? should return true and when false.
As I see from example it should return true if there are were made appropriate number of bookings each day during date_begin..date_end period. Am I right?

Comment: Mmmh I don't think so. I've updated the question with an example and changed the method in order to make it a bit more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but sample implementation is still confusing and always returns true. It looks like that you missed return statement inside cycle (return false if nb_places_taken_this_day >= self.places).
Now I see that your method should return true if the number of bookings each day of this period is less than number of places.

Comment: Oops, the return statement is mandatory you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have easy enough data to test this throughly, but I'm thinking something like this can work. Here I'm building into your query the condition that no booking exists where the start and end dates are not either both before or both after the requested dates. That is, every booking that does exist had better have either start and end before the requested start, or start and end after the requested end. If there exists a booking that does not meet this condition, then the requested dates are not available as a single booking. Does this work?

[EDIT - modified from original broken answer to reflect the actual problem]

This new answer still loops over days, but does so after grabbing all the conflicting bookings in one query. The ruby loop itself will be pretty quick.

(Note that the :all? method will immediately return false on the first false value and will return true if all elements evaluate to true, so adding the `return false unless` as suggested by the edit I believe is superfluous. In any case I've added a `return` to the last line to hopefully clarify the intent.)

```
  def available_between?(date_begin, date_end)
    conflicting_bookings = self.bookings.where.not("(date_begin < :requested_start_date AND date_end < :requested_start_date) OR (date_end > :requested_end_date AND date_end > :requested_end_date)", requested_start_date: date_begin, requested_end_date: date_end)
    return (date_begin..date_end).all? do |day|
      num_bookings_for_day = conflicting_bookings.select{|booking| booking.date_begin <= day && booking.date_end >= day}.count
      num_bookings_for_day < self.places
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't think it works. I just add an example. The last execution of `available_between?` would return false with your implementation because B1 would match your query. You miss the `places` information. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, missed the bit about places. Does the newly modified method cover it?

Comment: Not really. Consider an offer with 2 places and 3 bookings. The bookings are 1 day long and consecutives. A additional booking *can* be made during these 3 days because there is still one place left (each day). Your query would return 3 conflicting bookings and fail for this additional booking. However there is only *one conflicting booking per day* in this example.

Comment: Good point. Given then that the concept of a "day" is hard to represent in the SQL data, I think another approach is warranted. I'd suggest grabbing all overlapping bookings in 1 query then doing a loop in ruby to determine if all the days have at least one available place. I'll post this as a new answer. Is a day the smallest resolution of time that you care about? (i.e. can a booking be for part of a day?)

Comment: Stack overflow suggested I modify the current answer rather than posting a new one, so I did that instead.

Comment: I like your idea. Yes, one day is the smallest. Actually, only the nights are importants, but we don't need to go into these kinds of details so don't care about this ;).

Comment: To expand upon the edit-rejection, try `[1,2,3].all?{|x| puts x; x.odd?}` in the console. You'll see 1 and 2 puts'd, but it never evaluates the 3 in the loop. So :all? gives you the "stop and return false on the first false value" behavior for free.

Comment: Got it, you're right. `all?` is nice. What about the count after the select?

Comment: You're right! I didn't see that, good catch. I can't re-open the previous edit, so if you make another one I can accept it so you get the points for it.